# No GUI on Ubuntu 18.04 after reinstalling

Tags: apt, gnome, updates

I just reinstalled Ubuntu using Resetter. But when my desktop rebooted, there was no GUI. I used the command:
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
Some packages were installed, but then it shows two errors: hash sum mismatch and unable to fetch some archives, run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing. I'm new to Ubuntu. How can I get a gnome on my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Update, fix packages dependencies, upgrade:

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt upgrade
```

You could also try to install `gdm3` or `lightdm` display managers and switch to them:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

or

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then you could also try to start or restart them by:

```
sudo systemctl start gdm3
```

Display manager is responsible for gnome session launching in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked!but the password I had set says failed to start session